# deleting label less node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

using a query I have a list of nodes.

```
match (n) where n.afield is null return count(n),labels(n) ;
```

which gives

```
+---------------------------+
| count(n) | labels(n)      |
+---------------------------+
| 7        | ["foo"]   |
| 21       | []    |
(...)
```

If I want to delete all foo labeled node, I would use

```
match(n:foo) detach delete(n) ;
```

now, how can I delete all labelless node ? (those 21 in sample above)

```
match (n) where magic(n) detach delete ;
```

anyone know some kind of `magic(n)` ?

Comment: You're aware that `match(n:foo) detach delete(n)` would delete all :foo labeled nodes, not just the ones missing the property that you matched to earlier, right? And as far as label-less nodes, did you want to delete all nodes without a label, only label-less nodes missing the `afield` property?

Comment: @InverseFalcon yes and yes, see my edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this query to delete node without labels:

```
MATCH (n) where size(labels(n)) = 0
DETACH DELETE n
```